# State change is resetting the ng-model value that belongs in the parent scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a pretty simple dropdown:

```
<select ng-model="object.property" ng-change="update(object)">
  <option value="null">None</option>
  <option ng-repeat="option in options" value="{{option.id}}">{{option.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Associated with it, a simple update function :

```
$scope.update = function(object) {
    return $http.put('/api/object/'+ object.id, object)
};
```

For various reasons, I have the model loaded in the parent scope, so they persist after we left this state. This data is not reloaded when we come back.
The issue here is that whenever I change state, the dropdown gets destroyed, and all the properties are reset and saved.

I might be able to correct this by detecting the state change and not saving; and reloading the data when we come back, but this feels like a dirty hack.
Is there a cleaner way to stop the destruction of the state from affecting my models?

Thank you very much!

Comment: can you make a fiddle

Comment: You should store your data in a **service**, not in a parent scope (controller is re-instanciated).

Answer (score 0):

And after updating Angular and ui.router to the latest version, the problem was no more. (Along with about three other bugs)

Lesson learned.